# Opengl switch to immediate mode

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to switch from "vbo mode" to immediate mode in opengl and backward?

When debugging, I find it easier to just go glBegin(...) than to setup vaos, vbos etc..

In my init() function, there's this:

```
if (!(GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader && GLEW_ARB_fragment_shader))
{
    Log::instance() << "glsl not ready.\n";
    return false;
}
```

Does it initiate the shaders state and means I can't go back to fixed function pipeline?

Edit:
My initialization:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(1600,900);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 50);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL4");
    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(0);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyboardUp);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyboard);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(specialKeyboardUp);
    glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
    ...
GLenum result = glewInit();

    if(result != GLEW_OK) {
        Log::instance() << "glewInit() error.\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (!(GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader && GLEW_ARB_fragment_shader))
    {
        Log::instance() << "glsl not ready.\n";
        return false;
    }

    //opengl stuff
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glClearColor(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: It depends on the OpenGL context. If you use core then you are stuck with the functions in that version. If you use a compatible context, then it is backwards compatible. This all depends on which API is initialising that OpenGL context.

Comment: I use glew. How do I know if I'm using core or compatible context?

Comment: How are you creating the window? Usually if you aren't explicitly asking for a core context, you will get a compatibility context.

Comment: We should see how you are initialising your OpenGL context. Are you using GLFW, SDL or any other?

Comment: I use freeglut. I should mention that my real purpose is really just to draw a sphere.